# Getting a count of attributes with a given value

Tags: xquery

I'm trying to construct `XQuery` that will return the count of the number attributes found that have a value of `x`.

This is part of `SQL` query and these counts will fill one of the columns returned (that part I can figure out, it's the actual `XQuery` to get the count I haven't figured out yet.)

For example, if I have `<element elementattribute=1>...</element>`, how would I count all the `@elementattributes` that equal 1 for a given chunk of `XML`?

Comment: Ok, I think I stumbled on the answer myself:

I took the xml_content.value('count(//element[@elementattribute="1"]', 'int') to get the count.  Really the only problem I'm having now is how to specify this attribute for any element as it can occur in more than one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use an asterisk wildcard for the element name:

count(//*[@elementattribute='1'])

Hope that helps...

Comment: alternatively, you could also do:

count(//@elementattribute[.='1'])

Comment: You can also do:
`count(//*[@elementattribute=(1, 3)])`
to count values equal to 1 or 3.